# How to create a UTF8 string using WM_KEYDOWN key codes for barcode/QR code scanner

Tags: c#, winforms, qr-code, barcode-scanner, imessagefilter

I'm having an issue decoding a string using `WM_KEYDOWN` messages intercepted by an Application MessageFilter. Customers using my production app can use any standard USB barcode scanner (e.g. this [model](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WG1ZKZR)) to search for items and regardless of make or model these devices send messages to a focused WinForms control (e.g. `TextBox`) that are identical to typing the same characters on a keyboard only faster than most humans can type.

*For example, go into Notepad or WordPad or Word or any WinForms text box, scan this QR code and it just works. No code required because a "USB scanner" is just an input device that behaves like a keyboard.*

[image: qr code]

The next release adds QR code support and now I'm having issues because the incoming strings are more complex.

---

Even if there is no currently focused text box to receive the key messages, my app still needs to detect a barcode scan and reliably perform the query. For this reason, I've installed a MessageFilter for the main form in order to intercept WM_KEYDOWN and append the key code to a `Buffer` class so that I can detect the *rate* of incoming keystrokes. The rate detection scheme works great but my problem is decoding the messages properly because the QR code renders in raw format.As a hack, I can feed those characters into a dummy control that exists solely for this purpose and *it* knows exactly what to do with that key sequence.

[image: hack before-and-after]

Of course, I'd like to understand what the text box is doing internally so I can construct the UTF8 string directly without having to resort to that. What's the secret?

---

Here's my code, which also measures the *rate* at which the key messages are happening in order to distinguish whether the input is coming from human or a scanner:

- *Typing* "01234566789" echoes the string to the text box.
- *Scanning* "0123456789" should make a popup message instead.

Another requirement is that upon detection, the scanned text will be removed from the focused control (if there is one).

```
public partial class BarcodeScannerForm : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    public BarcodeScannerForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Add message filter to hook WM_KEYDOWN events.
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        Disposed += (sender, e) => Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if(m.Msg.Equals(WM_KEYDOWN)) detectScan((char)m.WParam);
        return false;
    }
    private void detectScan(char @char)
    {
        if(_keyCount == 0) _buffer.Clear();
        int charCountCapture = ++_keyCount;
        _buffer.Append(@char);
        Task
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SECONDS_PER_CHARACTER_MIN_PERIOD))
            .GetAwaiter()
            .OnCompleted(() => 
            {
                if (charCountCapture.Equals(_keyCount))
                {
                    _keyCount = 0;
                    if(_buffer.Length > SCAN_MIN_LENGTH)
                    {
                        BeginInvoke(()=>MessageBox.Show(_buffer.Text));
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

---

This is the version of `Buffer` that has the problem:

```
class Buffer
{
    public Buffer(Form owner) { }
    StringBuilder _sbScan = new StringBuilder();
    public void Append(char @char)
    {
        _sbScan.Append(@char);
    }
    public string Text => _sbScan.ToString();
    public int Length => _sbScan.Length;
    public void Clear() => _sbScan.Clear();
}
```

This is the hack version that gets the correct result by feeding characters through a TextBox, but doing this seems likely to have a negative impact on the rate detector.

```
class Buffer : TextBox
{
    public Buffer(Form owner)
    {
        // Must be visible and owned by main form to work
        Size = new Size();
        owner.Controls.Add(this);
    }
    public void Append(char @char) => Text.Append(@char);
    public int Length => TextLength;
}
```

Comment: This seems unnecessary - use a barcode scanner that can be used as a USB [SerialPort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) device.

Comment: What about trapping `WM_CHAR` instead?

Comment: @user09938 Enumerating and bit-banging IO with a COM port is familiar to me from my Arduino robotics days. But serial port isn't how you read a normal _keyboard_ in a WinForms app, is it? And since a USB _scanner_ behaves identically to a USB _keyboard_ it's hard to see how something like that is even remotely desirable.

Comment: @Jimi looks like you saved me yet again. If you care to post that I'll certainly accept it as the answer.

Comment: @IVSoftware: According to your post you aren't using a _normal keyboard_ you're using a barcode scanner. _since a USB scanner behaves identically to a USB keyboard it's hard to see how something like that is even remotely desirable_: Where's the `F11` key on a barcode scanner? When I first started working with a barcode scanner I too attempted to use it as a HID device, until I learned how to use it as a `SerialPort` device and learned the limitations of using it as a HID. But perhaps you're programming skills are better than mine were at the time and you haven't encountered those limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Jimi for showing me the answer that eluded me by being too darned simple.

---

Scan detector requirements:

- Works for both barcodes and QR codes
- Works whether or not there is a focused `TextBox` to receive incoming key events.

---

**SOLUTION**

Install a MessageFilter for the main form in order to intercept WM_CHAR and append the char code to `StringBuilder` class.

```
public partial class BarcodeScannerForm : Form, IMessageFilter
{        
    public BarcodeScannerForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Add message filter to hook WM_KEYDOWN events.
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        Disposed += (sender, e) => Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }
    private readonly StringBuilder _buffer = new StringBuilder();
    const int WM_CHAR = 0x0102;
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        // SOLUTION DO THIS (Thanks Jimi!)
        if (m.Msg.Equals(WM_CHAR)) detectScan((char)m.WParam);
        // NOT THIS
        // if(m.Msg.Equals(WM_KEYDOWN)) detectScan((char)m.WParam);
        return false;
    }
```

The detector algorithm appends each new character to the buffer and restarts a 100 ms watchdog timer. If the WDT expires without a new keystroke, it checks to see how many characters have been received. If the count is > 8 it's considered a scan.

```
    private void detectScan(char @char)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@char);
        if(_keyCount == 0) _buffer.Clear();
        int charCountCapture = ++_keyCount;
        _buffer.Append(@char);
        Task
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SECONDS_PER_CHARACTER_MIN_PERIOD))
            .GetAwaiter()
            .OnCompleted(() => 
            {
                if (charCountCapture.Equals(_keyCount))
                {
                    _keyCount = 0;
                    if(_buffer.Length > SCAN_MIN_LENGTH)
                    {
                        BeginInvoke(()=>MessageBox.Show(_buffer.Text));
                    }
                }
            });
    }
    int _keyCount = 0;
    const int SCAN_MIN_LENGTH = 8;
    const double SECONDS_PER_CHARACTER_MIN_PERIOD = 0.1;
}
```

Comment: I've updated my GitHub [repo](https://github.com/IVSoftware/barcode-scanner-01.git) with the code that works.