# what is the correct event I need to use when scan barcode?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make attendance system in C# windows forms by using barcode scanner

I used the following stored procedure to insert the ID NO and datetime for attendance:

```
private void txtCustomer_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   cust.add_attendence(txtCustomer.Text, DateTime.Now);
}
```

the issue now with the TextChanged event it made insert for each character in the database
for example if the id no = 2023 then it inserted like the following :

```
2    2023-03-08 00:06:00.217
20   2023-03-08 00:06:01.500
202  2023-03-08 00:06:01.760
2023 2023-03-08 00:06:02.020
```

this is not correct I need to insert one time after reading the complete barcode.

which event I need use or what I need to change in the code ?

Comment: what do the docs of the barcode scanner say. If all else fails you should wait for a second or 2 til there are no more text change events

Comment: Why not simply check the length of the text, and if length is x run your code? I would advise to implement a save button instead of that automatically insert.

Comment: @RandRandom how to check the length this is good idea if length 10 for example then insert ?

Comment: Well `if (txtCustomer.Text.Length == 10)`

Comment: @RandRandom but suppose the length not fixed length some with 6 some with 4 some with 10 numbers how to insert for example after 5 seconds of scan?

Comment: I would have assumed that a barcode is always a given length if you deal with the same type of barcodes, but could easily be wrong

Comment: @RandRandom yes if length fixed this will be correct answer I tried it with fixed length and its working thank you :)

Comment: If your scanned codes vary in length, there is an answer you may find helpful. It intercepts keyboard character messages and does some rate detection to determine whether a human or a machine is doing the "typing".  It also detects scans regardless of which control has the focus. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75163926/5438626 There is also a demo project on GitHub. You could [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/barcode-scanner-01.git) it to see whether it would be a good fit for your project.